# Regression network: Which loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression

My network (AlexNet for the beginning) outputs 4 real numbers, which are roughly in the region of 1e-7, 1e-5, 1e-2, and 1e-1. This is, they differ strongly among themselves.

I use sgd with 0.9 momentum und 1e-5 initial learning rate and 5e-4 L2 regularization.

At first, I used the forward loss L = 0.5*(y-t)^2 (y... output vector, t... target vector) as well as the backward loss dL/dy = y-t. In this case, the network doesn't converge and all 4 elements of y were in the same region 1e-2.

Then I tried to use relative errors instead of absolute errors. L = 0.5*((y-t)/t)^2 and dL/dy = (y-t)/t. As a result, the y values went to infinite.

Can anybody explain these results?

Comment: It's very difficult for a network to converge to weights that differ in many order of magnitudes. It's better to normalize your data so that it all is on the same order of magnitude and then train on the normalized data; the original data can be obtained from the inverse transformation then.

Comment: you should normalize your data so values are [0, 1]